# authentication/http headers support in forge.file trigger.io module?

Tags: mobile, module, http-headers, trigger.io

in the official trigger.io docs there seems to be no provision for **custom http headers** when it comes to the ***forge.file*** module. I need this so I can download files behind an http authentication scheme. This seems like an easy thing to add, if support is not already there.

any workarounds? any chance of a quick fix in the next update? I know I could use ***forge.request*** instead, but I'd like to keep a local copy (*saveURL*).

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the file module just uses simple "download url" methods rather than a full HTTP request library, which makes it a fairly big task to add support for custom headers.

I've added a task to our backlog for this, but I don't have a timeframe for it being added.

Currently on iOS you can do basic auth by using urls in the form `http://user:password@url.com` in case that helps.

Maybe to avoid this you can configure your server differently, or have a proxy server in front that allows you to pass authentication details as get parameters?